# ImportError: cannot import name 'init_osx_clipboard'

Tags: linux, pandas

Using pandas 0.19.2 on Linux Mint 18

When I copy any table from Libre Calc / MS Excel and run

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()
```

I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6dead334eb54> in <module>()
----> 1 df = pd.read_clipboard()

/home/prashant/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/clipboard.py in read_clipboard(**kwargs)
     23             'reading from clipboard only supports utf-8 encoding')
     24 
---> 25     from pandas.util.clipboard import clipboard_get
     26     from pandas.io.parsers import read_table
     27     text = clipboard_get()

/home/prashant/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/util/clipboard/__init__.py in <module>()
     31 import os
     32 import subprocess
---> 33 from .clipboards import (init_osx_clipboard,
     34                          init_gtk_clipboard, init_qt_clipboard,
     35                          init_xclip_clipboard, init_xsel_clipboard,

ImportError: cannot import name 'init_osx_clipboard'
```

How to resolve this?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you provide a few example rows of the table that causes the error when copied?

Answer (score 0):

The [`clipboard`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/util/clipboard/__init__.py) documentation may shed some light on your issue, given that you're running on Linux:

> On Linux, install `xclip` or `xsel` via package manager.
>   For example, in Debian:
>   `sudo apt-get install xclip`
>   Otherwise on Linux, you will need the `gtk` or `PyQt4` modules installed.
>   `gtk` and `PyQt4` modules are not available for Python 3,
>   and this module does not work with `PyGObject` yet.

Comment: Thanks. xclip is already installed but still getting the same message.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried on Ubuntu 16.04 with Libre Calc and `xclip` (Python 3.6, Anaconda, Pandas 0.19.2), and `read_clipboard()` worked fine with a simple table.  Maybe something's corrupted with your Pandas installation, have you tried removing and reinstalling?

Comment: Yeah. Reinstalled Linux Mint 18 but this is still not working.